# How to wait until canvas has finished re-rendering?

Tags: canvas, promise, html5-canvas, settimeout, synchronous

I have a `renderText()` function that fills out the canvas with text (`ctx.fillText(char, charLocation, 400)`). I want it to render the text, pause for 2 seconds, and render new text.

Workaround:

```
renderText();
setTimeout(() => {
    renderNewText();
}, 2000);
```

This solution is fine for now, but what if I want to decrease it to 0.1 seconds, and `renderText()` takes more than 0.1 seconds to execute, resulting in `renderNewText()` executing before `renderText()`? How can I, for sure, wait until `renderText()` is finished with `fillText` before pausing however long I want to pause?

What I know: I'm aware that `canvas` and `context` render entirely synchronously; as such, `renderText()` doesn't return any promises and all the methods called on the context continue even after exiting `renderText()`. Also, there are no events that can signal when it's done, at least according to all the comments and threads I've read. In all the solutions I've looked up on Stack Overflow, the answer is pretty much "You can't", but I find that hard to believe.

I'm sure there must be something I'm really not getting here, probably the event loop or Promises or something else.

Comment: if `renderText` is really `ctx.fillText(char, charLocation, 400)` then no worry, it is synchronous, there is no chance renderNewText gets called before.

Comment: canvas api calls are asynchronous, sure, but they're queued, so the order is preserved. To know more about this, read up on the event loop. If you have a race condition, it's somewhere else

Comment: Thanks to both! I think I get what "synchronous" means for JS now and how queueing works with the various commands. Thanks for easing my mind over this matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @towc's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51959904/eli5-how-to-wait-until-canvas-has-finished-re-rendering?noredirect=1#comment90878347_51959904)

> canvas api calls are asynchronous, sure, but they're queued, so the
>   order is preserved. To know more about this, read up on the event
>   loop. If you have a race condition, it's somewhere else